# How to print values of Material-Ui redux form to Material-Ui Table after pressing Submit button?

Tags: redux, redux-form, react-redux-form

I have a FieldArray input in my redux-form and want to print the values of that form on the table. I am new to React but have some JavaScript experience. I want to have the values of the form to print on the table . .......................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

APP.JS -

```
    const renderMembers = ({ fields, meta: { error, submitFailed } }) => (
     <ul> 
        <li> 
        <FloatingActionButton onClick={() => fields.push({})}> 
          <ContentAdd />
        </FloatingActionButton>

          {submitFailed && error && <span>{error}</span>}
       </li>

        {fields.map((member, index) => ( 
      const {
        handleChange, 
        handleSubmit,  
        pristine, 
        values,
        reset, 
        submitting 
         } = props

      return (
        <MuiThemeProvider>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>

          <FieldArray name="members" component={renderMembers}/>
          <div>
          <RaisedButton disabled={submitting}
          type="submit"
          label="Submit"
          labelPosition="after"
          primary={true}
          icon={<ActionAndroid />}
            />
          />
          </div>
      </form>
      <div>
      <Table>
      <TableHeader>
            <TableRow>
              <TableHeaderColumn>ID</TableHeaderColumn>
              <TableHeaderColumn>First Name</TableHeaderColumn>
              <TableHeaderColumn>Last Name</TableHeaderColumn>
              <TableHeaderColumn>List of Hobbies (1 - 5)</TableHeaderColumn>
            </TableRow>
          </TableHeader>
          <TableBody>
            <TableRow> 
              <TableRowColumn>want to print the value here</TableRowColumn>
              <TableRowColumn>want to print the value here</TableRowColumn>
              <TableRowColumn>want to print the value here</TableRowColumn>
              <TableRowColumn>want to print the value here</TableRowColumn>
            </TableRow>
            </TableBody>
      </Table>
      </div>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
      );
    };   

    class App extends Component {


      render() {
         return (
          <div className="App">

            <SignInForm onSubmit={this.submit}  />

          </div>
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please don't use caps lock (or say things like URGENT). All that will do is make people downvote you. Also, please reduce your code to make it as minimal as possible.

Comment: I am new to this. So Please help. I apologize for using caps.